# SQLite database limits in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm planning Android app which extensively uses local DB. DB would contain approx 15 tables , properly normalized  (FK, PK etc).  4 Main tables would have up to 1000 entries and about 15 columns with text, date/time and numbers only.

I wondering whether this configuration is feasible on Android phone/tablet.
Am I pushing sqlite and Android OS to the limits?
I cant find any firm figures about sqlite limitations on Android OS.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compelety agree with **@Amokrane's** answer but insure that your database should also have backward compactibility. Because you are saying that your database is properly normalized (FK , PK etc). And here `Foreign Key` support is only available since the `SQLite version 3.6.19` therefore this constraint could only be applicable on the `Android 2.2 FroYo` (which has `SQLite 3.6.22 Version`) and the above versions.

For more information refer : http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the source, where you've read that froyo supports this sqlite version.

Comment: @WarrenFaith:You can easily find it by using the commands **`adb shell`** and then **`sqlite3`** on your command prompt or terminal. It will displays all this information. See this link [Examining sqlite3 Databases from a Remote Shell](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

This [official SQLite limits page](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) contains many information that you might find interesting.

By the way, I don't think you are pushing SQLite to its limits 15 columns/ 1000 entries is not that huge!

Answer (score 1):

I've provided an answer to a similar question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759907/dealing-with-a-large-database-in-android/4760447#4760447) There are details of soft limits and size limits for the table.  As far as @Amokrane answer, you'll also need to be aware of limitations not imposed by SQLite, but by android.  50mb is the current maximum app size and there are issues with accessing large datasets on device.  Take a look at that answer.