# How to use Berkeley DB SQL API in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, berkeley-db

My Android program has a huge DB overload and also involves multiple processes (Apps) accessing the database at the same time. Obviously, I found the bundled `SQLite` DB engine insufficient.

So I closed in on Berkeley DB, and since I don't want to port my code to support NoSQL databases, I would like to use Berkeley DB SQL API and not the Berkeley Java Edition.
Can someone tell how do I use this in my Android program?

I could find absolutely no links on this. Mine is an Android Application, so I cannot build a custom firmware which replaces SQLite with BerkeleyDB.

Comment: "My Android program has a huge DB overload and also involves multiple processes (Apps) accessing the database at the same time." -- this is not a good idea. It does not matter whether you use SQLite or BDB or whatever. Flash is slow regardless, multiple processes consume too much RAM regardless.

Comment: @Commonsware The multiple processes are inevitable here. They are different apks part of a suite. They can't be bundled into an app for various reasons. Also, I need better DB support like processing over 10,000 records and encrypting DB etc, which SQlite can't provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dealing with a large database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759907/dealing-with-a-large-database-in-android)

One of the answers on this question has the answer you're looking for (I think). Second one down.

Comment: I started from that post. It does not give specifics of how we 'build' the BDB SQL API for Android.

Comment: The gentleman who posted the answer offered to help anyone who had any questions as he works as a developer on the Berkley DB. You might drop him a line and see if he can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It's been a day, he has not turned up yet! :|

Comment: Sorry... I'm travelling this week and don't have much spare time. :-( Can you post your questions to the Berkeley DB forum at http://bit.ly/eIREhr You'll find an active community of BDB and BDB SQL/Android developers there who can help you more quickly than I can.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely many ways to archive this, one without using the Java Edition is [cross-compiling the C code and using the Java bindings](http://www.occasional-coding.com/cross-compiling-berkeley-db-for-android).